# Passing row as an argument to a function in R dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing a program that calculates the difference between an element of a dataset and the rest of elements. I'm using dplyr mutate and I need to pass the entire row as an argument to a function which calculates the difference. Using iris as a example:

```
#Difference function
diff_func <- function (e1, e2) {
  return(sum(e1-e2))
}

chosenElement <- iris[1,1:4] # Chosen element
elements <- iris[10:50,1:4] # Elements to compare to

elements %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(difference=diff_func(chosenElement, c(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)))
```

This works, but as I use the entire row, I would like to use something like "this" or "row" instead of specifying all the columns of the row:

```
elements %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(difference=diff_func(chosenElement, row))
```

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this very easily in `base R` by replicating the chosenElement to make the dimensions same

```
elementsNew <- elements - chosenElement[col(elements)]
```

---

Note that `mutate` is for changing/transforming the values of a single column/multiple columns -> a single column.  Of course, we can place other types of objects in a `list`.  Assuming that the 'difference' should be for each column of 'elements' with that of corresponding element of 'chosenElement', the `mutate` is not doing that with the `diff_func`

#### Update

Based on the clarification it seems we need get the difference between the columns with the corresponding chosenElement (here we replicated) and then do the `rowSums`

```
elements %>%
        mutate(difference = rowSums(. - chosenElement[col(.)]))
```

Comment: The 'difference' is the score for a full row. For example:
elements[1,] is:
4.9  3.1  1.5  0.1

chosenElement is:
5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2

The difference between their values (chosenElement - elements[1,]) is:
0.2  0.4  -0.1 0.1

So, what I want is to add an extra column with the sum of those values: 0.2 + 0.4 -0.1 + 0.1 = 0.6:

4.9  3.1  1.5  0.1  0.600

Comment: @AlfonsoJiménez  I updated the post.  Can you check if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` `base` combination:

```
do.call(cbind,purrr::map2(elements,chosenElement,function(x,y) x-y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `(a - d) + (b - e) + (c - f) == (a + b + c) - (d + e + f)`, it's just a difference between row sums of the `elements` and sum of `chosenElements`, which you can do within base R:

```
elements$dfrnce <- rowSums(elements) - sum(chosenElement)
```

Or, in `dplyr`:

```
elements %>%
  mutate(dfrnce = rowSums(.) - sum(chosenElement))
```